# How to disable the scrolling of the body when the navbar collapse is active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3, i am facing problem with disabling the body scroll when the collapsible nav-bar menu is open in mobile devices. when the collapse menu is open and if we swipe over it, the background element also starts scrolling which i don't want. i want that background element should not scroll when we swipe over the collapsible menu. The same problem is also seen in desktops.

Comment: Can you post a link to your project or provide us with a Jsbin?

Comment: the website is https://finlife.ga

Comment: in mobile if we swipe over  the collapse nav bar the background container starts scrolling. same is with other devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this with CSS is to disable the overflow of the `html` and `body` elements.

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<!-- Example HTML which would normally create a scrollbar -->
a<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
b<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
c<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
d<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

You could create a class called `no-scroll` and apply it to `html` and `body` when you open the menu. Remove the class when the menu closes.